# libgdx TiledMapRenderer upper layer texture bleeding

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

The issue is as follows :

My textures are all padded by 2px and the padding (and I have set texture padding to 2px in the tiled editor) seems to solve the bleeding, but only at the first layer it seems

[image: -bleeding-]

*My speculation is that the TiledMapRenderer renders the first layer with duplicate padding logic to solve the bleed that reveals the game background, but the logic is not applied at higher layers because they usually wont hide the game background*

The thing is I do not know if I am right about my spec and I do not know how to solve this issue

My tiled editor texture config:

[image: -texture config-]

And my texture:

[image: -padded tileset-]

Help is much appreciated